# Primary techniques to prevent against hacks when passing user input to CLI arguments?

Tags: input-validation, cli

What are the main kinds of hacks that can be used when passing user input from the command line, and what are the key techniques to prevent against them (like to prevent against browser XSS attacks, you typically escape the HTML before rendering in the DOM).

But for the command-line, I've only just started to think about potential problems and solutions, so wondering if they have been aggregated before, or if we can do so here. Some situations:

- **File paths accessing things outside of a desired folder.** So if you want all generated file read/write to occur in the `/tmp` folder, you need to make sure users don't do `/tmp/../usr/stuff` to access private folders.
- **Executing subshell commands or piping**. I imagine if you have a command like `convert {input} {output}` (an imagemagick command), you could pass in `input: "2> /dev/null", output: "| cat some-os-private-config-file"` or perhaps `input: "2> /dev/null &&", output: "echo $(which node)"` or something. So you would have `convert 2> /dev/null && echo $(which node)`.

So what are the best ways to generically mitigate against these sorts of problems? What are the main things to handle? What to check for basically on each input argument? If it's too complicated, what are the main complexities? What are the key things to be aware of when implementing this system?

Comment: Web applications and command line tools are not comparable. Web applications don't provide users any access to operating system. Where as command line tools have *purpose* to allow user to interact with the operating system. For command line, it is the *purpose* to allow usage of any paths, to allow usage of commands piping. Any restrictions are usually done by other means, namely be permissions. Command line tools are executed in user context. Which means that for command to execute some actions, user must have permission for this action.

Comment: ... All examples what you show are absolutely legitimate. If user should not be able to do particular operations, they should be prohibited on the OS level.

Comment: *"So what are the best ways to generically mitigate against these sorts of problems?"* - I don't see any problems. Again, the best way to deal with permissions is to use permission system of particular OS, e.g. standard Linux permissions or SELinux.

Comment: @mentallurg So I am building a browser/REST API for doing things like convert documents with the `pandoc` CLI tool, and other things of that nature (there are no easy to use non-CLI tools for these kinds of things). So you're saying I need to make the OS "user" have certain permissions for all my commands (on my remote EC2 instance, for example)? Any chance you could link to relevant solution for that, or explain what I need to do briefly? I am no OS security expert by any means.

Comment: To the `pandoc` command I might have to pass a "format" option, so have to validate the format isn't some unknown value. But wondering how much security work I have to do, and of what kind. Some things like formats I check against an enum, but other things like some CLI option which is an arbitrary string, I need to at least limit against some sorts of hacks.

Comment: Currently I have about 50+ CLI tools I am building an interface on top of. FontForge, LibreOffice, Pandoc, etc.. I often pass user input unvalidated to these commands (as of now, nothing of which is released). So I need to know better what to do. Each command is located in various spots, and needs access to various things. It is unclear to me what I need to lock down from an OS standpoint in this situation.

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/OS_Command_Injection_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @Lance: You are saying *"CLI arguments"*. This is a wrong description of what you are actually doing. In case of "pandoc" we cannot speak of any "mitigation", because otherwise you should say you need mitigation for all the code that all the developers create. Please describe the problem more precisely. In particular, add to the question what you wrote in the comment, because comments can be deleted after the question was clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tough to get a hold on any statistics (in regards of the command-line-specific context).

However here are some of the most common attack vectors and their mitigations (unordered, [enumerated](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-coding_theory))

## **A. AttackVectors and their Mitigations**

1. **Command Injection** - Strict parsing
2. **Path Traversal** - Privilege separation
3. **Argument Injection** - Strict parsing
4. **Symlink Attack** - Privilege separation
5. **Race Condition** - Atomic operations
6. **Input/Output Redirection** - Secure file handling
7. **Privilege Escalation via Sudo** - Minimize required permissions
8. **Wildcard Expansion** - Literal argument handling
9. **Script Injection** - Escaping special characters
10. **Environment Variable Manipulation** - Environment sanitization
11. **Integer overflow** - Larger datatypes, Static Analysis
12. **Buffer overflow** - [Stack Canaries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries), [DEP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable-space_protection#Windows), [ASLR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)
13. **Format String Vulnerabilities** - Don't use Printf-'Methodfamily'-members

In case your source for the commands to be run is a public / unknown system,
you probably should also consider to:

## B. Additional security considerations

- Try to separate concerns physically (userinput, execution stack on different systems.)
- Before transferring the commands to the executing system use a formatter-module that string-replaces language-symbols ***; {} () [] = == != > < >= <= ! & && || + - * / % ^ " '; (*** rendering a *not* run- but analyzable, secure form that can be used for generating semantic heuristics
- **Important**: Deploy a white-listing-strategy to which every distinct invokable command needs to be added to and run against.
- Don't execute directly, Develop a parser and an execution-helper which can save metadata for long-term machine learning-analysis.
- Run the executing system in a container inside a hardened SELinux
- Create a distinct Useraccount with stripped power limited
- Use a strict least required permission-system.
- Monitor Logfiles, Diff Sequential Result-History, addCheck for ir-regularities.
- Setup a simple Reset-command for programmatically cleaning the system that was under attack.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.